# Can I analyze synonyms words before create the index in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, analyzer, synonym

I'm trying to configure synonyms in ElasticSearch. My problem is that I'm using other filters before synonym ones and, when the synonym filter acts the word that it have is different.

This is my index:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "my_synonym_filter": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "synonyms": [
            "judía,haba=>haba"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_synonyms": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding",
            "spanish_stop",
            "spanish_stemmer",
            "my_synonym_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When 'judía' appears in the text, the firsts filters return 'judi' for indexing, and when "my_synonym_filter" acts the word 'judía' is different than 'judi' and it's not recognized as synonym.

Is there any way to analyze the synonyms before create the index?

I would like to maintain the synonym word as 'judía' and not change in the filter declaration by 'judi'.

Thank you for your time and your answers.

Comment: This is probably due to spanish_stemmer Applyin synonyms filter before Spanish stop/word filter would that cause an issue ? i.e.``"filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding",
            "my_synonym_filter","spanish_stop","spanish_stemmer"
          ]``

Comment: But in that case when "my_synonym_filter" acts 'judía' and 'judia' are different and I would lika that the synonym affect to both.

Comment: What stops you from adding synonym filter twice? Just place it before `asciifolding` filter.

Comment: But if I put twice, before `asciifolding` and at the end, if the synonym word is 'judía' and the word in the text to index is 'judia' before `asciifolding` 'judía' != 'judia' and at the end 'judía' != 'judi'. I have the same problem in that case.

Comment: Can you put the filters in this order:
"filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding",
            "spanish_stop",
            "my_synonym_filter",
            "spanish_stemmer"
          ]

Comment: It's not exactly the use that I would like but definitely I'll put the filters in this order. Thank you very much.